# Example $f\in L^p([0,1]) \backslash L^q([0,1]) $ and $g\in L^p(R) \backslash L^q(R) $?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, improper-integrals, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

I want to find two examples $f\in L^p([0,1]) \backslash L^q([0,1]) $ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})  \backslash L^q(\mathbb{R}) $ given $1\leq p < q < \infty$.

It turns out the two examples I found are the same to some extent.

Set $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^b}.1_{(0,1)}$ with $b\in (1/q,1/p)$. We will show that $f\in L^p([0,1])$ but $f\notin L^q([0,1])$. Indeed, we have $1-pb\in (0,1-p/q)$, hence
        $$
  \int_\mathbb{[0,1]} f(x)dx=\frac{x^{1-pb}}{1-pb}|^1_0<\infty.
  $$
        But  $1-qb\in (1-q/p,0)$, hence
        $$
  \int_\mathbb{[0,1]} f(x)dx=\frac{x^{1-qb}}{1-qb}|^1_0=\infty.
  $$

Miraculously, this works for $\mathbb{R}$ as well

We will show that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ but $f\notin L^q(\mathbb{R})$. Indeed, we have $1-pb\in (0,1-p/q)$, hence
        $$
  \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx=\frac{x^{1-pb}}{1-pb}|^1_0<\infty.
  $$
        But  $1-qb\in (1-q/p,0)$, hence
        $$
  \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx=\frac{x^{1-qb}}{1-qb}|^1_0=\infty.
  $$

Am I wrong somewhere? Thanks

Comment: Since the function is just 0 off of [0,1] it should be no surprise that it is in $L^p$ and not $L^q$ after expanding the domain. I suspect the problem wanted you to find a different $f$ which is in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ and not $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: you mean this example is correct, but the problem wants me to define a function in a larger domain?

Comment: I mean that I think they switched the order of p and q in the second part and you misread it.